# wxpython: table with checkbox

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I need something like this below.

[image]

Requirements,

1. when top level checkbox is selected all children should be selected
2. When root level checkbox is selected then all should be selected
3. an event binding each checkbox so that whenever user check/uncheck a checkbox I can do some calculation based on the check/uncheck events
4. User should be able to collapse/expand the parents

I have checked `wxTreeCtrl` and `wxListCtrl`, looks like I can not add checkboxes. How can I do this in wxpython?

python version 2.7.

Comment: I suspect `wx.grid` can handle this. I found [this example](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Change%20wxGrid%20CheckBox%20with%20one%20click) but have not tested it.

Comment: Take a look at `wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl` https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl.html#module-wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl